# node chaining then no return

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I am new to `async` function and I'm tring to chain some function but I can't figure out why I can't return the last call

```js
var container = { Login: '', sign_up_text: '', forget_password: '', login_button: '' }
var lang = 'de-DE'
var langID = 1

async function getVars (key, lang){
    return db.localization.findOne({
        where: {
            key: key,
            lang: lang
        }
    })
}
async function getLangID (lang){
    return db.localGroups.findOne({ where: {
            i10s: lang
        },
        attributes: ['id']
    })
}
async function getLocalvars (container, lang){
    var newcontainer = container
    for (let key in container) {
        console.log(lang)
        await getVars(key, lang)
            .then(data => {
                newcontainer[data.key] = data.value;
            })
    }
    return newcontainer;
}
async function desprate() {
    getLangID(lang)
        .then(langdata => {
            getLocalvars(container, langdata.id)
                .then(data => {
                    console.log(data);
                    return data;
                })
        })
}
console.log(desprate());
```

Not even a promise shows up in the log ;(

Thank you!

Comment: Neither your `desprate` nor your outer `then` return anything.

Comment: Can you tell me pls more 
i think i missunderstand something "data" (console.log(data)) has the right stuff in it

or do you mean in desprate i need to return the second then to the function itself ?

Comment: Why are you using `.then()` instead of `await` in the `async function desprate`?

Comment: truth be told i dont know better yet it is my first example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll give this a shot. I haven't tested this but I'll try to hit the key concepts here in the comments.

```js
var container = {
  Login: '',
  sign_up_text: '',
  forget_password: '',
  login_button: '',
};
var lang = 'de-DE';
var langID = 1;

async function getVars(key, lang) {
  return db.localization.findOne({
    where: {
      key: key,
      lang: lang,
    },
  });
}

async function getLangID(lang) {
  return db.localGroups.findOne({
    where: {
      i10s: lang,
    },
    attributes: ['id'],
  });
}

async function getLocalvars(container, lang) {
  var newcontainer = container;
  // since you're iterating over an object you will have to await all the promises that result in the loop
  await Promise.all(
    Object.keys(container).map(async (key) => {
      const data = await getVars(key, lang);
      // since this is an async function you can just await it rather than chaining it with then
      newcontainer[data.key] = data.value;
    })
  );
  return newcontainer;
}

async function desprate() {
  // let's again take advantage of async/await here
  const langdata = await getLangID(lang);
  const data = await getLocalvars(container, langdata.id);

  console.log(data);
  return data;
}

console.log(desprate());
```

Comment: thank you! is it then right way to send the data 
like
```js 
desprate()
    .then(data => {
        console.log(data);
    })
```
after some hours sleep and seeing it again it makes total sense now to wait for the iteration o.O thank you very much i am totally new to this and this whas my first hellmarry atempt to use multiple async function

Comment: No worries at all. We've all been there. Yeah if you use `then` you gotta make sure you `return` from `then` so the next chain will get what you returned. And if you use `async`/`await` then make sure you don't use `then` as it's much easier with `await` :)